# JavaScript SonarLint Eclipse Violations Differ from SonarQube

Tags: javascript, sonarqube, sonarlint

Running SonarLint in Eclipse (4.6.2) in connected mode to SonarQube (6.4) using vanilla "Sonar way" rules for JavaScript, and seeing huge differences in the number of issues caught on the server vs. Eclipse.

Example, foo.js has 5 bugs listed on server, but only 2 reported by the Linter (and one of the two is a different bug than those caught on server). So, Linter is catching 1 of the 5 bugs found by SonarQube, and 1 of its own.

I have confirmed that I'm properly connected and even updated bindings. Java file violation counts are either exact or very close between server/eclipse, but JS is way off on counts for all files.

Help on identifying/solving this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say 5 bugs are listed on SonarQube but only 2 in SonarLint, can you tell me the rule ids of the 3 bugs that are not listed in SonarLint? You can find the rule id in the details of the rule description. I suspect those rules don't come from official SonarSource plugins, but from 3rd parties. SonarLint only shows issues from SonarSource plugins.

Comment: Using a new example (bar.js)...  

Sonar finds 3 blockers, and 3 majors:  
- 3x "Trailing commas should not be used" (TrailingComma)  
- 2x "Dead stores should be removed" (S1854)  
- "'for...in' loops should filter properties before acting on them" (ForIn)  
  
Lint finds 1 blocker, 4 majors, and 2 minors:  
- "Variables should be declared explicitly" (S2703)  
- 2x "Variables and functions should not be redeclared" (S2814)  
- 2x "Dead stores should be removed" SAME LINES SONAR CAUGHT ABOVE (S1854)  
- 2x "Unused local variables and functions should be removed" (UnusedVariable)

Comment: The solution is to bind the projects (SonarLint > Bind to a SonarQube project...) and use the "SonarLint Report" tab, _not_ the SonarLint On-The Fly tab. OTF doesn't bind to the server at all... it uses local rules.

Comment: I can assure you that OTF uses the rules as configured on the server, when you are bound to a project on the server.

Comment: You are correct. I just checked, and OTF is now working where it was not previously.

Comment: Now the original issue has been reversed... we're getting more violations in SonarLint than Qube. So Qube catches 1, Lint catches 9 (the 1 Qube issue is included in the 9 LInt catches). The rules being caught are the same ones, but Lint finds more instances of, say, "Unused function parameters should be removed" than Qube does.